# How do I access a superclass's constant property within Matlab?

Tags: oop, matlab, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a simple class structure like so:

```
classdef super < hgsetget
    properties(Constant = true, Access = private)
        PROP1 = 1;
        PROP2 = {2 [3 4] [5 6]};
    end

    methods
        function self = super()
            // Constructor code here
            // ...
        end
    end
end
```

which is then inherited by a subclass like so.

```
classdef sub < super
    properties
        PROP3 = 7;
    end

    methods
        function self = sub()
            // Subclass constructor here
            // ...
            self = self@super();
            test = self.PROP1; // I don't appear to have access to PROP1 from Super

        end
    end
end
```

My issue is when I try to access to the super's property `PROP1` or `PROP2` I don't seem to get access:

> No appropriate method, property, or field PROP1 for class sub.

Is there a way to access to the super's property within Matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In superclass `super` set properties attributes to

```
properties(Constant = true, Access = protected)
```

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html) an access attribute determines what code can access these properties:

- public — Unrestricted access
- protected — Access from methods in class or subclasses
- private — Access by class methods only (not from subclasses)

Answer (score 2):

You define the properties as `private`, those are not inherited.

Use `Access = protected` instead.